# Multi-instance XML file to CSV with Headers and Column Mappings

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I am trying to convert an multi-instance XML file, where a parent node, could have 2 or more child nodes of the same kind.

Essentially, I have this type of XML file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Report_Data>
   <Report_Entry>
      <field1>Record1_field1</field1>
      <field2>Record1_field2</field2>
      <field3>Record1_field3</field3>
      <Report_SubEntry>
         <subField1>Record_1subfield1</subField1>
         <subField2>Record_1subfield2</subField2>
         <subField3>Record_1subfield3</subField3>
      </Report_SubEntry>
      <Report_SubEntry>
         <subField1>Record1_subfield1_subEntry2</subField1>
         <subField2>Record1_subfield2_subEntry2</subField2>
         <subField3>Record1_subfield3_subEntry2</subField3>
      </Report_SubEntry>
   </Report_Entry>
      <Report_Entry>
      <field1>Record2_field1</field1>
      <field2>Record2_field2</field2>
      <field3>Record2_field3</field3>
      <Report_SubEntry>
         <subField1>Record2_subfield1</subField1>
         <subField2>Record2_subfield2</subField2>
         <subField3>Record2_subfield3</subField3>
      </Report_SubEntry>
   </Report_Entry>
 </Report_Data>
```

The XSLT function has to be re-usable for similarly structured XML files, without having to hard-code loops or conditions for all the possible sub-entry types.

This is my XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs this ws">

    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" media-type="text/plain"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'§'" />
    <xsl:param name="quote" select="''" />
    <xsl:param name="break" select="'&#xA;'" />

    <!--
        List of Fields to be included in final CSV.
        !! Use only XPATH node names with prefixes. !!
               If prefixes are to be removed from the header, update the 
    -->

    <xsl:variable name="fieldArray">
        <field>field1</field>
        <field>field2</field>
        <field>field3</field>
        <field>subField1</field>
        <field>subField2</field>
        <field>subField3</field>
    </xsl:variable>



    <xsl:param name="fields" select="document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='fieldArray']/*" />

    <xsl:template match="//Report_Entry">

        <!-- output the header row -->
        <xsl:for-each select="$fields">
            <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:for-each>

        <!-- output newline -->
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Report_Entry"/>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//Report_Entry">
        <xsl:variable name="currNode" select="." />

        <!-- output the data row -->
        <!-- loop over the field names and find the value of each one in the xml -->

        <xsl:for-each select="$fields">

            <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />

            <xsl:variable name="child" select="$currNode[*]/*/*[name() = current()]" />
            <xsl:variable name="childSecondLevel" select="$currNode[*]/*/*/*[name() = current()]" />
            <xsl:variable name="childThirdLevel" select="$currNode[*]/*/*/*/*[name() = current()]" />

            <xsl:choose>

                <xsl:when test="count($child) > 0">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$child"/>
                </xsl:when>

                <xsl:when test="count($childSecondLevel) > 0">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$childSecondLevel"/>
                </xsl:when>

                <xsl:when test="count($childThirdLevel) > 0">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$childThirdLevel"/>
                </xsl:when>

                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$currNode/*[name() = current()]" />
                </xsl:otherwise>

            </xsl:choose>

            <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />

        </xsl:for-each>


        <!-- output newline -->
        <xsl:value-of select="$break" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The Output that I get is:

```
field1,field2,field3,subField1,subField2,subField3
Record1_field1,Record1_field2,Record1_field3,Record_1subfield1,Record_1subfield2,Record_1subfield3
Record2_field1,Record2_field2,Record2_field3,Record2_subfield1,Record2_subfield2,Record2_subfield3
```

But the output I need is:

```
field1,field2,field3,subField1,subField2,subField3
Record1_field1,Record1_field2,Record1_field3,Record_1subfield1,Record_1subfield2,Record_1subfield3
Record1_field1,Record1_field2,Record1_field3,Record_1subfield1_subEntry2,Record_1subfield2_subEntry2,Record_1subfield3_subEntry3
Record2_field1,Record2_field2,Record2_field3,Record2_subfield1,Record2_subfield2,Record2_subfield3
```

Does anyone have suggestions on approaching this?

Answer (score 0):

How about the below.

I am looping through the `Report_SubEntry` instead of the `Report_Entry`, meaning for each `Report_SubEntry` you will get one row.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- Output header -->
    <xsl:text>f1,f2,f3,sf1,sf2,sf3&#xa;</xsl:text>

    <!-- Loop through all children of Report_Entry that have childen themselves -->
    <xsl:for-each select="/Report_Data/*/*[*]">
        <xsl:variable name="strCurrentNode" select="name()" />

        <!-- Output parent values -->
        <xsl:for-each select="../*">
            <xsl:if test="name() != $strCurrentNode">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <!-- Output child values -->
        <xsl:for-each select="./*">
            <xsl:if test="name() != $strCurrentNode">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />

                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <!-- output newline -->
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks! This does the job. In reality, the structure of the subnodes differs, and that displaces the columns. That was the purpose of the fieldArray in my original snippet - to always form columns in the CSV correctly, even if a node or sub-node is missing. I'll take your feedback to loop through the lowest nodes and get parent values instead of always children or siblings. Thanks!

Comment: NP, remember to click the tick so it's marked as answered. If you are unsure if there will always be at least one SubEntry but want to output the parent values then you can Loop through the Entry's (for-each), check if there are Sub_Entry's (choose->when), if there are, loop through the Sub_Entry's(for-each), outputting Sub_Entry data and ../Entry data, if there are no Sub_Entry's(choose->else) then just output the Entry data. Hope that makes sense, little hard to write in comments.